# JavaScript unexpected asynchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a file uploader for my blog system which would just let users drop files in it and it would automatically upload them to server. Strangely (for me), `console.log` outputs dataArray before it gets filled, while calling it after a timeout outputs it correctly.

For example, if I drop 4 files on my drop area, I would get this:

```
[]
[file1, file2, file3, file4]
```

Then I drop 4 more files without uploading/refreshing and I get:

```
[file1, file2, file3, file4]
[file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8]
```

So my script is working asynchronously for some reason? Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var dataArray    = [];

$('.dropArea').bind(
{
    drop: function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

        $.each(files, function(index, file)
        {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onload = (function(file)
            {
                return function(e)
                {
                    var image = this.result;

                    dataArray.push({
                        name : file.name,
                        value: image
                    });
                }
            })(files[index]);

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

                    console.log(dataArray);
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(dataArray) }, 1000);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `console.log()` in the callback.

```
fileReader.onload = (function(file)
{
    return function(e)
    {
        var image = this.result;

        dataArray.push({
            name : file.name,
            value: image
        });

        console.log(dataArray);
    }
})(files[index]);
```

if you call it outside of the callback, it will run immediately after the image is **starting to load** instead of when the images are **finished loading**.

I've quickly drawn an image for clarification:

[image: description]

You can solve this by comparing the amount of images that is dropped and the amount of images that finished loading, like so:

```
var dataArray    = [];
var count = 0; // amount of files dropped
var ready = 0; // amount of files finished loading

$('.dropArea').bind(
{
    drop: function(e)
    {
        ...

        $.each(files, function(index, file)
        {
            count++; // we start handling a file here so we increment

            ...

            fileReader.onload = (function(file)
            {
                return function(e)
                {
                    ...

                    ready++; // this image has finished loading so we increment
                }
            })(files[index]);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(ready === count) {
                // all images have been loaded
                console.log(dataArray);
            }
        }, 1000);
    },
});
```

Comment: Was just about to ask if there is an event for when file is loaded, but you were faster. It's a pity that there is no way to bulk-queue files for loading and make it fire event when everything is done :( . Thanks a lot for your response and effort !

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Tim S. answered, onload event is fired when file **starts** loading, and it can take some time depending on file size. Here is how I solved discovering if all files are loaded.

```
drop: function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log(files.length + " queued for upload");

        var counter = 0;
        var loaded = 0;
        $.each(files, function(index, file)
        {
            counter++;
            console.log("File #"+counter+" loading started.")
            if (!files[index].type.match('image.*'))
            {
                $('.dropArea').html(message.error.onlyImage);
                errorMessage++;
            }
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onload = (function(file, count)
            {
                return function(e)
                {
                    var image = this.result;

                    dataArray.push({
                        name : file.name,
                        value: image
                    });

                    loaded++;
                    console.log("File #"+count+" loaded.");

                    if (loaded == files.length) {
                        console.log("Loading finished!");
                    }
                }
            })(files[index], counter);

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }
```

And really, console log output looks like this:

```
4 queued for upload 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:25
File #1 loading started. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:32
File #2 loading started. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:32
File #3 loading started. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:32
File #4 loading started. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:32
File #2 loaded. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:52
File #4 loaded. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:52
File #3 loaded. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:52
File #1 loaded. 9a840a0_part_2_dragndrop_2.js:52
Loading finished!
```

As can be seen, file #2 was loaded first because it is the smallest one, while #1 loaded last while it is the largest.